# Call a method only one time per user session

Tags: session, spring-mvc, controller

I would like to call a method of my Spring Controller only one time per user session.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user.html")
public String getUser(Model model) {
    doSomethingAtEachCall();    
    doSomethingOnlyOneTimePerSession(); // call only first time user access to this page
    return "user";
}
```

How can I do that (properly) ?

Comment: can't you extract that use of method to a `@PostConstruct` method? That would do the trick if the class itself is sessionscoped.

Comment: No, because I am dependent of the call of this specific url...

Comment: Sadly over that I have only hack ideas, with use of a boolean flag, but that is probably not the best solution.